# ngOnInit not being called after router.navigate

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-routing

My Angular app is all of a sudden not calling `ngOnInit()` after `router.navigation()` which means my components do not load correctly. I thought it may have been due to some changes I made but reverting the changes did not resolve the issue.

Example where normal navigation causes component not to load correctly; This page is navigated to by the following code listing:
`this.router.navigate(['/result', this.params.data._id]);`:

[image: Component not loaded correctly]

Reloading the page, the component is loaded correctly:

[image: Component loaded correctly]

Here are some of my code listings,

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AgGridModule.withComponents(
            [SampleResultButtonComponent]
        ),
    ChartsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,

    LoginComponent,
    LogoutComponent,
    SignupComponent,

    FilesComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
    UploadComponent,
    SampleGridApplicationComponent,
    SampleResultButtonComponent,
    AssetGridApplicationComponent,
    ResultComponent,
    ResetPasswordComponent,
    AssetComponentDetailComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
  entryComponents: [AssetComponentDetailComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
    @Injectable()
export class NoAuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  canActivate() {
    const activeUser = Kinvey.User.getActiveUser();
    if (activeUser) {
      return true;
    }

    // Navigate to the login page
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  canActivate() {
    const activeUser = Kinvey.User.getActiveUser();
    console.log("AuthGuard, CanActivate");
    if (!activeUser) {
      return true;
    }

    // Navigate to the main page
    this.router.navigate(['']);
    return false;
  }
}

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: NavbarComponent,
    canActivate: [NoAuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: '', component: SampleGridApplicationComponent },

      { path: 'files', component: FilesComponent },
      { path: 'upload', component: UploadComponent },

      { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },

      { path: 'sampleitems', component: SampleGridApplicationComponent },
      { path: 'assetitems', component: AssetGridApplicationComponent },
      { path: 'result/:id', component: ResultComponent}

    ]
  },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent },
  { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'reset', component: ResetPasswordComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {useHash: true})
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthGuard,
    NoAuthGuard
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**EDIT**
After some more digging I believe the issue is related to the issue [here](https://github.com/Kinvey/angular2-sdk/issues/5) however the suggested fix does not resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: Updated with code listings.

Comment: Your screenshots show different components being loaded... The first shows `SampleGridApplicationComponent` and the second shows `ResultComponent`. Is this what you're expecting?

Comment: This is the issue, `SampleGridApplicationComponent` is the component from the previous route and `ResultComponent` is the component for the current route. The components are not being loaded when using router.navigate.

Comment: Updating question with possible cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem ended up being a bug in angular router, downgrading to version 4.1.3 fixed the issue. Hopefully this helps anyone else that tries using the latest version of angular with the Kinvey SDK.

Comment: Care to elaborate on the details of the bug? Why is it happening? What is the nature of the issue? Which cases are affected?

Answer (score 14):

It seems this problem is still around, even after 5.0 has been released, at least the issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18254 is not yet resolved. The good news is that there is a workaround described in the issue, using:

```
        this.zone.run(() => {
          this.router.navigateByUrl( url );
        });
```

I had the problem in the onAuthStateChanged callback for Firebase, and the above workaround helped.

Comment: Care to elaborate on the details of the bug? Why is it happening? What is the nature of the issue? Which cases are affected?

Comment: I also got same problem at version 5+. Thanks! I can found a solution from the [issue link](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18254)

Comment: I got the same issue after upgrading from angular 5.2.0 to angular 6. Thanks

Comment: Also saw this problem with `@angular/router@7.2.0`. Running `NgZone` manually as suggested here fixed the problem. As of this writing, I don't understand exactly why this was needed.