# Angular OnInit not triggered after routing to component

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I just ran into a very weird problem I've never had with the angular router before.

I'm using a [leaflet plugin](https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet) to display some map markers related to my underlying dataset. In order to get to more detail information about these places a click on one of the markers should route the user to another component called `detail` by passing the respective dataset id within the url (`detail/:id`).

However, in this case the component is loaded and the constructor is called, but the implemented `OnInit` function is not triggered as normally. There's just nothing happening there.

All this can also be seen in this stackblitz [example](https://stackblitz.com/github/hG3n/map-routing-test).

Is this a known bug in the current release of Angular (6.0.5)? 
If so, is there a workaround?

Cheers and thanks in advance

Comment: IDK yet but it has something to do with calling router from event callback. Investigating

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clicking on marker runs logic outside of NgZone which prevents change detection from happening. You need to run it manually.
Inject `NgZone` into `MapComponent`

```
export class MapComponent {
...
  constructor(private router: Router, private ngZone: NgZone) {...}
```

Then change

```ts
 marker_label.on('click', (event: MouseEvent) => {
            const link = ['detail', id];
            this.router.navigate(link);
        });
```

to

```ts
marker_label.on('click', (event: MouseEvent) => {
            const link = ['detail', id];
            this.ngZone.run(() => this.router.navigate(link))
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess it would've taken me a long time to find that out :D

Comment: I checked my answer after Antoniosss pointed out it was not working and he was right so I deleted it. I got to the same workaround that czen did but he was faster so upvote for him! :-)  By the way this  has been answered before  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44745354/ngoninit-not-being-called-after-router-navigate